# Field 'id' doesn't have a default value when import excel file laravel

Tags: laravel

```
return new hasilsurvey([
            'survey' => $row[1],
            'question1' => $row[2], 
            'question2' => $row[3], 
        ]);
```

I has setting my table columns 'id' to primary key but still get same problem

Please help my problem

Answer (score 0):

When creating your migration you must define `id` field as autoincrement:

```
$table->bigIncrements('id');
```

If you want to update id field for that table you can do it with this:

```
$table->bigIncrements('id')->change();
```